# I am so confuse with Outer join 3 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to do outer join three table. My database is sakila database.

[image: Sakila]
I am trying to get film title rows that have never been rented. So, I join three table like this.

```
SELECT f.title
FROM film f
LEFT OUTER JOIN inventory i ON f.film_id = i.film_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN rental r ON i.inventory_id = r.inventory_id
WHERE r.rental_ID IS NULL;
```

It returns row but the problem is I don't know this query is right or wrong. Can someone help me?

Comment: On a sidenote: It looks strange that a film is linked directly to a store.Maybe the diagram is incorrect? It rather looks like a film is linked to an inventory that belongs to a store.

Comment: @VincentLynn . . . Your query is fine.  There are other ways to express the logic using `NOT IN` or `NOT EXISTS`.

Comment: BTW: This is a database I'd use composite keys for. For instance: A payment is made for a rental from a store to an employee of the same store. Or so it should be. Single technical IDs don't guarantee this. You'd need composite keys to guarantee such consistencies.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks. Just learned that NOT IN OR NOT EXIST existence in SQL. :)

Comment: If the problem concerns 3 tables, then we need to see three tables (and CREATE and INSERT statements for each - together with the desired result). We do not need to see ER diagrams of your entire schema. In fact we do not need to see ER diagrams ever.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be using [an `EXISTS` clause instead as this allows a sub-query](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html) and to test is that returns rows or does not:

```
SELECT f.title
FROM film f
JOIN inventory i ON f.film_id = i.film_id
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM rental r 
    WHERE i.inventory_id = r.inventory_id
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting films from the film table. You are outer joining inventories and rentals. Then you keep all NULL rentals. This is a so-called anti join, a trick used on weak DBMS to mimic `NOT EXISTS` or `NOT IN` clauses, that these DBMS fail to perfom well on.

The query thus gives you all films that either have no inventories at all or that have inventories, but not a single rental. Or short: films that have no rentals. Exactly, what you say you want to achieve.

Another way of writing the query is:

```
select title
from film f
where not exists
(
  select *
  from inventory i
  join rentals r on r.inventory_id = i.inventory_id
  where i.film_id = f.film_id
);
```

Comment: Thank for your answer. I am very new to SQL and professor haven't taught  NOT EXISTS, EXISTS yet. So, I am trying to achieve by trying what I taught in the class.

Comment: Wow, it's great that you have already been able to write a proper anti join. Well done; your query is fine. But your prof should hurry up to teach `[NOT] IN/EXISTS`. They make queries more readable. As you can see from my query, it is obvious that we select films where some condition is met (namely: no rentals). Criteria is in the `WHERE` clause here, where it belongs.